# Replace Div and Reset Div (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a DIV with links in it.  When a link is clicked I wish to replace div in place with a form. When users need to return 'home' to original div they should simply click 'go back' or similar.

Here's what I've tried with no prevail:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
  <div class="container" id="init">
    <div class="link-1">
      <a class="first" href="#">1st Action</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-2">
      <a class="second" href="#">2nd Action</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-3">
      <a class="third" href="#">3rd Action</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container" id="one" style="display:none;">
  <input type="button" value="Go Back" id="home"/> One
</div>

<div class="container" id="two" style="display:none;">
  <input type="button" value="Go Back" id="home"/> Two
</div>

<div class="container" id="three" style="display:none;">
  <input type="button" value="Go Back" id="home"/> Three
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var originalState = $("#init").clone();

$(".first").click(function() {
  $("#init").replaceWith($("#one"));
});

$(".second").click(function() {
  $("#init").replaceWith($("#two"));
});

$(".third").click(function() {
  $("#init").replaceWith($("#three"));
});

$("#home").click(function() {
  $(<current state>).replaceWith($(originalState));
});
```

Where I would like to replace div (id="init") with the corresponding selected div (id="one",id="two", or id="three").

Furthermore user need to return to original div (id="init") upon clicking 'go back button'

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/remmi11/hv19pu37/15/).

Comment: you cant replace it with something that's a child replaceWith('<div id="three"></div>); if you want to use the browser back button you'll need to use # navigation or similar, your fiddle is missing JS

Comment: The second answer below meets all requirements including history support. Can you please review and accept if it works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic solution with javascript (no jQuery) hope it helps you and solves the problem.

```js
const initDiv = document.getElementById('init');
    const classList = ["first" , "second" ,"third"];
    const inputClassList = ['one' ,'two' ,'three'];
    let linkIndex = -1;
    initDiv.addEventListener('click' , showInput);

    function showInput(e){
       
        let linkIndex = classList.indexOf(e.target.classList[0]);
        if(linkIndex >= 0){
            const inputDiv = document.getElementById(inputClassList[linkIndex]);
            const inputButton = inputDiv.children[0];
            
            inputDiv.classList.remove('noDisplay');;
            initDiv.classList.add('noDisplay');

            inputButton.addEventListener('click' ,function(){
                initDiv.classList.remove('noDisplay');
                inputDiv.classList.add('noDisplay');
            })

        }
    }
```

```css
#wrapper{
background-color: #999;
}

.noDisplay{
display:none;
}

.inputCss{
/*set here the css properties you don't want the input to 
enherit from wrapper div*/
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
        <div class="container" id="init">
          <div class="link-1">
            <a class="first" href="#">1st Action</a>
          </div>
          <div class="link-2">
            <a class="second" href="#">2nd Action</a>
          </div>
          <div class="link-3">
            <a class="third" href="#">3rd Action</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container noDisplay inputCss" id="one">
        <input type="button" value="Go Back" id="home1"/> One
      </div>
      
      <div class="container noDisplay inputCss" id="two">
        <input type="button" value="Go Back" id="home2"/> Two
      </div>
      
      <div class="container noDisplay inputCss" id="three">
        <input type="button" value="Go Back" id="home3"/> Three
        </div>
      </div>
```

***This solution is using jQuery.***

The [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method removes content from the DOM and inserts new content in its place with a single call.
So you can just modify the css display value.

```js
var originalState = $("#init").clone();

$(".first").click(function() {
    toggleDisplay("init" ,"one");
    $("input").click(function() {
    toggleDisplay("one" ,"init");
    });
});

$(".second").click(function() {
    toggleDisplay("init" ,"two");
    $("input").click(function() {
    toggleDisplay("two" ,"init");
    });
});

$(".third").click(function() {
    toggleDisplay("init" ,"three");
    $("input").click(function() {
    toggleDisplay("three" ,"init");
    });
});
function toggleDisplay(first ,second) {
$(`#${first}`).hide();
$(`#${second}`).show();
}
```

```css
#wrapper{
background-color: #999;
}

.inputCss{
/*set here the css properties you don't want the input to 
enherit from wrapper div*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
        <div class="container" id="init">
          <div class="link-1">
            <a class="first" href="#">1st Action</a>
          </div>
          <div class="link-2">
            <a class="second" href="#">2nd Action</a>
          </div>
          <div class="link-3">
            <a class="third" href="#">3rd Action</a>
          </div>
        </div>
     
      
      
        <div class="container inputCss" id="one" style="display:none;">
          <input type="button" value="Go Back" id="home1"/> One
        </div>

        <div class="container inputCss" id="two" style="display:none;">
          <input type="button" value="Go Back" id="home2"/> Two
        </div>

        <div class="container inputCss" id="three" style="display:none;">
          <input type="button" value="Go Back" id="home3"/> Three
          </div>
          
       </div>
```

Comment: I guess what I am trying to do is literally swap out div id='init' with div id='one', etc...  So that div="one" inherits css from parent div id="sidebar-wrapper"  Example: https://imgur.com/a/hh2nX

Comment: @NoahHuntington you can nest the divs containing the inputs inside the wrapper div so that it will inherit it's css properties when it's displayed.               I modified the code so that you get your desired result.

Comment: I am aware there likely exist more optimal solutions with javascript.  @ Firas your solution provided me with the complete jquery solution i was seeking.  Additionally this solution meets the css requirements I need (although this was not apparent in my initial question)

Answer (score 1):

**This solution meets all functional requirements including browser history support**. In other words, pressing the back or forward buttons work as expected.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). To test history controls, host the page locally.  The full source is attached below.

The key challenge is to not change the DOM or event bindings more than needed. The replace and clone operations are expensive and have weird edge behaviors. Usually it is better to hide and show elements and set event bindings as few times as possible.

The solution below does all this. Let me know if you have questions. Good luck!

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
    <div class="container" id="init">
      <div class="link-1">
        <a class="first" href="#">1st Action</a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-2">
        <a class="second" href="#">2nd Action</a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-3">
        <a class="third" href="#">3rd Action</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="one" style="display:none;">
    <input type="button" value="Go Back" class="home"/> One
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="two" style="display:none;">
    <input type="button" value="Go Back" class="home"/> Two
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="three" style="display:none;">
    <input type="button" value="Go Back" class="home"/> Three
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function () {
  var 
    allowList  = [ '', 'first', 'second', 'third' ],
    doDebounce = false
    ;

  $('.first').click(function( event_obj ) {
    $('#init').hide();
    $('#one').show();
    doDebounce = true;
    document.location.hash = 'first';
    event_obj.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.second').click(function( event_obj ) {
    $('#init').hide();
    $('#two').show();
    doDebounce = true;
    document.location.hash = 'second';
    event_obj.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.third').click(function( event_obj ) {
    $('#init').hide();
    $('#three').show();
    doDebounce = true;
    document.location.hash = 'third';
    event_obj.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.home').click(function( event_obj ) {
    $('.container').hide();
    $('#init').show();
    doDebounce = true;
    document.location.hash = '';
    event_obj.preventDefault();
  });

  $( window ).on( 'hashchange', function () {
    var
      page_str    = document.location.hash || '',
      selector_str = ''
      ;
    if ( page_str.length > 0 ) { page_str = page_str.substr( 1 ); }
    if ( allowList.indexOf( page_str ) === -1 ) { return; }
    if ( doDebounce ) { 
      doDebounce = false;
      return;
    }

    selector_str = page_str ? '.' + page_str : '.home';
    $( selector_str ).trigger( 'click' );
    doDebounce = false;
  });

}());
</script>
</html>
```